# Major Scale Ascending Formula in reverse direction

Tags: theory, sheet-music

I Know that major scale ascending formula is TTSTTTS (T-tone, S- semitone)
Using This we can find G major notes and those will be in the order GABCDEF#G (from left to right on keyboard)
So my question is what if we use the same formula to find G major notes but in reverse direction (from right to left on keyboard)
In this way Notes came out to be GFEbDCBbAbG
So does this mean anything if use this formula in the above way?
I hope U get my pt.

Comment: Well, that's, if you write it again bottom-to-top, [STTTSTT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrygian_mode). But you may consider this just a coincidence; it only works this way if you really interpret semi- and whole tones as fundamental entities (as in Pythagorean or 12-edo systems). It doesn't work in e.g. a Ptolemaic, harmony-guided understanding of scales.

Comment: I have just started learning music theory and the above is a bit difficult to understand.So, can u explain it in an easy way?

Answer (score 2):

Interesting theory! What you end up with is the major scale notes of Eb, with its 3 flats of Bb Eb and Ab. Except that doing it your way, starting on G, actually produces a mode of Eb called **G Phrygian**.

The concept of scales is that they are more easily considered as cycles rather than linear - as in when you get back to the start note, the cycle starts again. True, on a keyboard, the notes are laid ouy in a linear fashion, but name wise it's cyclic.

Modes, if they're new to you, are the same notes as a major scale (thus TTSTTTS), but the seven modes start on each of the different major scale notes. So - Dorian (the 2nd mode) starts on the second note, therefore the pattern is TSTTTST.

Comment: And thus Dorian is its own inversion!

Comment: @Richard - indeed - whichever way you look at it. 'Dorian: I can play that mode backwards...'

Comment: Amateur. I can play it backwards and upside down.

Comment: @Richard - that's a fair trick. I tried playing the piano standing on my head, but kept falling over... It was easier when I turned the *piano* upside down though...

Comment: Now you're getting some idea of what it's like being a musician here in the Land Down Under, where we have to spell that mode n-a-i-r-o-d and play it accordingly (with one hand tied in front of our back).

Comment: @AreelXocha - and exactly where is the observer standing when it's decided it's Down Under?  Could just as easily be Up on Top...

Answer (score 0):

The procedure you describe of running the steps (intervals) backwards can be called an **inversion**. The resulting notes of the inverted major scale make the **phrygian mode**. So you can say the inversion of the major scale is the phrygian mode.

You can do other inversions. For example, major chord inverted becomes a minor chord.